# Subtract 6 days and 23 hours from a Timestamp or Datetime in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a better way in BigQuery to subtract 6 days and 23 hours from a timestamp then using [TIMESTAMP_SUB()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_sub) or [TIMESTAMP_DIFF()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) twice:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SUB(
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 6 DAY), 
    INTERVAL 23 HOUR
)
```

Looks ugly to me, am hoping there's a way to use only one function call.
If not, a simple no will suffice. If yes or if there are good alternatives, I really like to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 167 HOUR) -- 6*24+23
```

Comment: Nice! :) Disadvantage is maybe that you lose an intuitive feel for how much you're going back in time, but thanks for the answer! Maybe writing 6*24+23 hour inside the function instead of 167 hour, is communicating more clearly to the reader of the query.

Comment: sure you can, if you have variables you can write @days_back*24+@hours_back or maybe if you need to go back 7 days minus 1 hour, (@days_back*24)-1. If you find the answer correct, please mark it as accepted.